# java annotation processor with grails

Tags: java, grails, groovy, annotations

I'm trying to create a custom annotation with grails. I don't think I need an AST transformation. I just want to add some validation before calling a method (with their params).

I've created the following:

**>interface (ValidateSomething.java)**

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface ValidateSomething {

}
```

**>processor (ValidateSomethingProcessor.java)**

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes({"annotations.ValidateSomething"})
class ValidateSomethingProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        System.out.println("Hello world! :D");
        return true;
    }
}
```

**> {grails root}/web-app/META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor**

```
annotations.api.ValidateSomething
```

**>TestController**

```
@ValidateSomething
def index() {
    println "test"
}
```

When I run the controller action, it only prints "test".

Did I forget anything? Do I have to do anything else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Annotation processing is a tool build in javac for scanning and processing annotations at **compile time** and not at runtime. What you want to do is intercept method call. To do so you can use java interceptor or aspectj.